# BufferedReader not fully reading a file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I have a file with 50 lines, each line just containing one word, and I have the following class to read a random line from the file:

```
public class WordGenerator{
    static Random generator;

    static int numberGenerator(){
        generator = new Random();
        return generator.nextInt(50)+1; 
    }

    static String wordSelector(){
        String word = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String temp = String.format("..%sutil%s", File.separator, File.separator);

        try{
            fis= new FileInputStream(temp + "Words.txt");
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("File not found: " + ex);
        }

    
        try{
            for(int i = 0; i < numberGenerator(); ++i){
                word = br.readLine();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error in line reading: " + e);
        }

        System.out.println(word);

        return word;
    }
}
```

The problem is that for some reason the class is never returning anything that is located after the first 5-10 lines and just keeps returning the first ones.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop calls `numberGenerator()` on every iteration.  This means that instead of picking a single random number from 1 to 50, you're drawing a new one each time through the loop.

By the time you get through 5 or 10 iterations, it's likely you've drawn a random number less than i.

While you're fixing that, move the `new Random()` instantiation outside of that method. You only need one random number generator, and you can keep calling `nextInt()` on it.  You're needlessly creating a new object every time.